# Hide and Show Toolbar on MediaController show() and hide()

Tags: android, toolbar, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I'm using a `MediaController` to control video play back for my `VideoView`. I've overriden `VideoView.setOnPreparedListener` so that the ActionBar/`Toolbar` is hidden (`hide()`) after the video first finishes buffering. And I'd like the toolbar to *comeback* when the `MediaController` does. I've tried **overriding** the `MediaController` `show()` and `hide()` methods, like so:

```
    mVideoView.start();
    // Media Controller
    mMediaController = new MediaController(this){
        @Override
        public void show() {
            getSupportActionBar().show();
        }
        @Override
        public void hide() {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
    };
    mMediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
    // Hide toolbar once video starts
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // Hide support bar
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
    });
```

This works, except the playback controls stop showing up! And of course, calling a recursive `mMediaController.show()` within the overridden method doesn't work... Can I have my cake an eat it too?

**Edit**

So I've also, unsucessfully tried taking advantage of the `VideoView.setOnTouchListener` and `VideoView.setOnCompletetionListener`:

```
    mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            getSupportActionBar().show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
    });
```

It does show, but it won't hide again, perhaps I misinterpret `OnCompletetionListener`?

**Edit 2**
From Amir's suggestion, I override the `onTouch` for `VideoView`, not *perfect*, but it's on like the right track:

```
    mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.media_player);
    mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        boolean flag;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if(flag) {
                        mMediaController.hide();
                        getSupportActionBar().hide();
                    } else {
                        mMediaController.show();
                        getSupportActionBar().show();
                    }
                    flag = !flag;
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This mostly works, it toggles the `Toolbar` and so sometimes the `Toolbar` will appear without the `MediaController`, and each time I toggle it, the `MediaController` does it's regular 'appear for a few seconds and then disappear.' In any case, it is a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your `OnTouchListener` a bit. I do following in my project and works fine:

```
final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            boolean flag = true;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if (flag) {
                            mediaController.hide();
                            hideToolbar();
                        }
                        else {
                            mediaController.show(0);
                            showToolbar();
                        }
                        flag = !flag;
                        return true;

                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            }
        });
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4"));
```

And **hideToolbar()** with some traslate animation:

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

**showToolbar():**

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

Also if you need to **HideStatusBar** call `setUiFlag()` with true:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
private void setUiFlags(boolean fullscreen) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        if (decorView != null) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(fullscreen ? getFullscreenUiFlags() : View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
private int getFullscreenUiFlags() {
    int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    }

    return flags;
}
```

Comment: So I tried this, and it hasn't worked. I tried declaring the MediaController in several locations, including before the onCreate method  (in order to declare `final`-- but when I do that, the app crashes because it cannot find the Context. Is that my issue?

Comment: @Nevermore it's not related to final value. which part of code cause exception? I just test this piece of code two hours ago and works.

Comment: @Nevermore also sometimes **setMediaController** cause exception put it  in try catch. Also set Internet permission in manifest.

Comment: So no exception comes up, it simply does not show the toolbar. Also yes, the permissions are all there, in fact the app works great otherwise. I'll post exactly the code I've tried in another edit.

Comment: @Nevermore sorry instead of **MotionEvent.Action_UP** use **MontionEvent.Action_DOWN**.

Comment: So this works! Thanks! Except clicking will toggle the toolbar and the mediacontroller will hide and show like normal -- meaning that sometimes the toolbar will be there, until I toggle it off, that is, it doesn't just turn on and off with the mediacontroller. In any case, accepted! thanks a lot.

Comment: define custom SimpleTouchEventListener will fix this issue ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your original code seems to work if you add calls to the corresponding super methods.

```
mediaController = new MediaController(this){
    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        getSupportActionBar().show();
        Toast.makeText(activity_media_player.this, "SHOW TOOLBAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void hide() {
        super.hide();
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        Toast.makeText(activity_media_player.this, "HIDE TOOLBAR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```